# What does >>= mean in python?

Tags: python, syntax, operator-keyword

What is happening here?

```
x = 5

x >>= 3

print(x)
```

the output is 0 and I can't understand why.

Comment: `x` right shift by 3 bits and assign back to `x`. `>>` is the right shift bit-wise operation. It's a shorthand similar to `x =+ 2` means `x = x + 2`.

Comment: just like `x += 3` is the same as `x = x + 3` . And then instead of the `+` you have a bitwise shift `>>` operator. This comment + the dupe link should explain everything for ya.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh It made me confused, thank you for your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shorthand for x = x >> 3. Since 5 >> 3 is 0 you get 0 as a result.

The operator >> is a right shift:

```
>>> bin(5)
'0b101'
>>> bin(5 >> 1)
'0b10'
>>> bin(5 >> 2)
'0b1'
>>> bin(5 >> 3)
'0b0'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a right shift operator.
Bit Pattern of the data can be shifted by specified number of Positions to Right

5 in bits =  101

101 >> 3. It will return zero.